# Assigning a function to each link after the onclick event

Tags: javascript, events

I want to separate my markup from the behavior but i stuck on how to associate the function i created to all the links in the document after the onclick event without including it directly in the markup. Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Image Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Snapshots</h1>
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="images/fireworks.jpg" title="A fireworks display" onclick="showPic(this); return false;">Fireworks</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="images/coffee.jpg" title="A cup of black coffee" onclick="showPic(this); return false;">Coffee</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="images/rose.jpg" title="A red, red rose" onclick="showPic(this); return false;">Rose</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="images/bigben.jpg" title="The famous clock" onclick="showPic(this); return false;">Big Ben</a>
</li>
</ul>
<img id="placeholder" src="images/placeholder.gif" alt="my image gallery">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/showPic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my script

```
function showPic(whichPic) {
"use strict";
var source = whichPic.getAttribute("href");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

placeholder.setAttribute("src", source);
}

window.onload = function() {
"use strict";
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

console.log(anchors);

for(var i = 0, count = anchors.length; i < count; i++) {
    //anchors[i].preventDefault;
   // anchors[i].onclick = showPic;
}
```

}

I tried to loop through the links and assign the function to the onclick event of each link but it didn't work. What is the best way this could be done so that behavior is completely separate from markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showPic(e) {
    // e is the event, e.target is the current element
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    var source = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

    placeholder.setAttribute("src", source);
}

window.onload = function() {
    "use strict";
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var i = 0, count = anchors.length; i < count; i++) {
        anchors[i].onclick = showPic;
        // Or you could use anchors[i].addEventListener('click',showPic);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove what's in the HTML.

#### JS Fiddle Demo

**On a side note**

[Void](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496715/void) mentioned using `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`. Both are acceptable, with a difference to keep in mind:

This code:

```
element.onclick = func1;
element.onclick = func2;
```

Will result in `func2` being called on click, but not `func1`. That is because it overwrites any previous `.onclick` statement on that precise element.

This code, however:

```
element.addEventListener('click',func1);
element.addEventListener('click',func2);
```

Will result in both `func1` and `func2` being executed, because they add up.

Answer (score 0):

Best Way

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"), function(el){
        el.addEventListener("click", function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           showPic();
        });
});
```

Comment: Yeah! , See updated answer. Hope it is nice now @blex

Comment: Check the update, Still sexy right? ;) And thanks mate. @blex

Comment: Haha yeah, it might be sexy, but it won't work either, because `.forEach` is used on arrays. `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` is not really an array, it's an object with properties. [**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/gj2e0ts5/)

Comment: Haha, Nothing like that.